# Index not found in mysql SELECT when selecting a foreign key

Tags: mysql

If I select a column which is not a foreign key in my table, I find the index:

```
mysql> explain SELECT id FROM stats_image_optimization_hourly WHERE stats_image_optimization_hourly.record_status=1;

+----+-------------+---------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------------------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                           | type  | possible_keys | key                       | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------------------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stats_image_optimization_hourly | index | NULL          | image_time_record_status3 | 9       | NULL | 1824413 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+-------+---------------+---------------------------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

If, on the other hand, select a column which is a foreign key, the index is not found:

```
mysql> explain SELECT server_id FROM stats_image_optimization_hourly WHERE stats_image_optimization_hourly.record_status=1;

+----+-------------+---------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table                           | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | stats_image_optimization_hourly | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1824413 | Using where |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here is the definition of the table:

```
stats_image_optimization_hourly | CREATE TABLE `stats_image_optimization_hourly` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `time_stamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `site_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `server_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `device_class_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `congestion_level_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `network_type_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `image_format_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hits` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `in_bytes` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `out_bytes` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `opt_pct` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `record_status` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `time_stamp` (`time_stamp`,`site_id`,`server_id`,`device_class_id`,`congestion_level_id`,`network_type_id`,`image_format_id`),
  KEY `fk_image_device_class_id3` (`device_class_id`),
  KEY `fk_image_congestion_level_id3` (`congestion_level_id`),
  KEY `fk_image_network_type_id3` (`network_type_id`),
  KEY `fk_image_site_id3` (`site_id`),
  KEY `fk_image_server_id3` (`server_id`),
  KEY `fk_image_format3` (`image_format_id`),
  KEY `image_time_record_status3` (`time_stamp`,`record_status`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_congestion_level_id3` FOREIGN KEY (`congestion_level_id`) REFERENCES `congestion_level` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_device_class_id3` FOREIGN KEY (`device_class_id`) REFERENCES `device_class` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_format3` FOREIGN KEY (`image_format_id`) REFERENCES `image_format` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_network_type_id3` FOREIGN KEY (`network_type_id`) REFERENCES `network_type` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_server_id3` FOREIGN KEY (`server_id`) REFERENCES `server` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_image_site_id3` FOREIGN KEY (`site_id`) REFERENCES `site` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2479561 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be related to index selectivity . You have an index on tinyint column which has very few distinct values compared to number of records. Unless index is covering for a query (like the first one - it's innodb table, and primary key column implicitly included in secondary index) , optimizer (based on statistics) decides that full table scan is cheaper than index range scan + lookup.

Answer (score 2):

You `id` is a primary key, and, as such, is a part of each index in an `InnoDB` table.

When you run your first query, all the data you need (filtering and selected fields) are contained in the index itself, so just scanning the index would be enough to run the query.

You can tell by `Using where; Using index` in the explain output: `using index` part means that it's the index-only scan.

In your second query, `server_id` is not the part of the index on `record_status`. This means MySQL, had it chosen the index access method, would have to look up the corresponding table record for every index record in a nested loop to retrieve the value of `server_id`.

This is quite a costly operation, and most your records have `record_status = 1` anyway (MySQL knows that because it keeps histograms of the index keys distribution).

So the optimizer chooses to do table-only scan instead, as all data are there in the table, and most of the table records would have to be retrieved anyway, but in a less efficient manner.